Traefik docker unable to proxy request to containers running in same host
I have a traefik reverse proxy running in docker container on machine (192.162.3.178), the proxy container is listening on port 80.
on the same machine I have another container running for piHole (port 81).
I'm trying to proxy any request with with <ip>/pihole to the pihole admin. I have tried different things at this point and it does not work on containers running the same machine.
I'm using the dynamic file to configure the proxy
## DYNAMIC CONFIGURATION
http:
  routers:
    portainer-proxy:
      entryPoints:
        - web
        - secureWeb
      middlewares:
        - "strip-prefix"
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/portainer`)"
      service: portainer-service

    pihole-proxy:
      entryPoints:
        - web
        - secureWeb
      middlewares:
        - "strip-prefix"
        - "add-dashboard"
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/pihole`)"
      service: pihole-service

  middlewares:
    strip-prefix:
      stripPrefix:
        prefixes:
          - "/portainer"
          - "/pihole"
    add-dashboard:
      addPrefix:
        prefix: "/admin"

  services:
    portainer-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "https://192.162.3.177:9443"

    pihole-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://192.162.3.178:81"

    proxy-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://192.162.3.178:8080"


